# how to use the default map of an android device

Tags: android, dictionary

is it possible in an android app to show the default map that is available in the android devices. If yes please tell me how to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send an intent of action `VIEW` and set the URI with a scheme `geo`.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) the `Google Maps` section